# Using c# iText in browser using Blazor WebAssembley to encrypt PDF client-side

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf, itext, blazor-webassembly

i'm looking to make an iFrame with Blazor that gonna upload a pdf an encrypt the pdf using iText like in this back-end example:

```
[TestMethod]
public void PdfEncryption()
{
  String SOURCE_FOLDER = @"C:\temp\lock\backup\";
  String initialFileName = SOURCE_FOLDER + "signed(1)-DocumentVide.pdf";
  String outFileName = SOURCE_FOLDER + "signed(1)-DocumentVide - iText.pdf";

  EncryptionProperties encryptionProperties = new EncryptionProperties();
  encryptionProperties.SetStandardEncryption(
    null, 
    System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("azer"),
    EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_ASSEMBLY|EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_COPY|EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_DEGRADED_PRINTING|
    EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_FILL_IN |EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_MODIFY_ANNOTATIONS|EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_MODIFY_CONTENTS|
    EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING|EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_SCREENREADERS|EncryptionConstants.DO_NOT_ENCRYPT_METADATA,
    EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_128
  );

  PdfEncryptor encryptor = new PdfEncryptor();
  encryptor.SetEncryptionProperties(encryptionProperties);

  using (PdfReader initialFile = new PdfReader(initialFileName))
  {
    using (FileStream outputStream = new FileStream(outFileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
      encryptor.Encrypt(initialFile, outputStream);
    }
  }
}
```

in my Blazor project i wrote it as this code:
File: upload.razor

```
@page "/upload"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms
@using iText.Kernel.Pdf
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime

<h3>Upload and Encrypt PDF</h3>
<InputFile OnChange="HandleFileUpload" />

@code {
  private async Task HandleFileUpload(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
  {
    var file = e.File;
    if (file != null)
    {
      // Read the uploaded file into a MemoryStream asynchronously.
      using var stream = file.OpenReadStream(maxAllowedSize: 1024 * 1024 * 15); // Limit to 15 MB files
      using var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
      await stream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
      memoryStream.Position = 0;

      // Set encryption properties
      var ownerPassword = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ownerPassword");
      var writerProperties = new WriterProperties()
          .SetStandardEncryption(
              null,
              ownerPassword,
              EncryptionConstants.ALLOW_PRINTING,
              EncryptionConstants.ENCRYPTION_AES_128
          );

      // Prepare the output MemoryStream for the encrypted PDF.
      using var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

      // Create PdfReader and PdfWriter instances to work with the PDF.
      using var reader = new PdfReader(memoryStream);
      using var writer = new PdfWriter(outputStream, writerProperties);
      using (var pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(reader, writer))
      {
        // Close the document so the encryption takes effect.
        pdfDoc.Close();
      }

      // Convert the output MemoryStream to a byte array.
      var encryptedContent = outputStream.ToArray();

      // Trigger the download of the encrypted PDF.
      await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("blazorDownloadFile", file.Name, encryptedContent);
    }
  }
}
```

File:index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>SEBlazorPDFHandler</title>
    <base href="/" />
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    
    <!-- If you add any scoped CSS files, uncomment the following to load them
    <link href="SEBlazorPDFHandler.styles.css" rel="stylesheet" /> -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app">Loading...</div>

  <div id="blazor-error-ui">
    An unhandled error has occurred.
    <a href="" class="reload">Reload</a>
    <a class="dismiss"></a>
  </div>
  <script src="_framework/blazor.webassembly.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.blazorDownloadFile = (filename, content) => {
      // Create a Blob from the PDF Stream
      var file = new Blob([content], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

      // Create an anchor element and click it to download the file
      var a = document.createElement('a');
      a.href = fileURL;
      a.download = filename;
      document.body.appendChild(a);
      a.click();

      // Delay for Firefox compatibility
      setTimeout(function () {
        document.body.removeChild(a);
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
      }, 100);
    };
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

But when i upload the pdf file i have this error:
[image]

What's wrong with my code.

My objectif of all this is to encrypt pdf client-side because i did't find a js library that can encrypt existing pdf client side

Comment: Your exception is not in sync with the posted code. The exception says that you cannot execute a Read on the stream variable (returned by file.OpenReadStream), I assume you created the PdfReader with the stream variable as parameter. But in your code you copy async the stream to a memoryStream and then load the PdfReader from the memoryStream.